# Parse match data for statistics

Tags: javascript

Hoping this question is not to broad..
In short: I am looking for a way to calculate and manipulate match statistics.

---

I have setup a simple website where we can put in scores form our tabletennis matches in the office. Now that I have a decent amount of data I would like to calculate some fun statistics and show them to my co-workers.
I am thinking stuff like: biggest wins-streak, who is my nemisis, win/loss ratio, favourite hour of the day to play matches, wins most matches in morning or afternoon, least productive colleague, ...

Now so far I have found how to calculate wins and losses, but by doing so I have made 3 database calls. So no good!!

Is there a way to calculate this or even a library made for this? There are so many websites out there that do this for professional games like soccer, NBA, ... Only thing I have found is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178590/extracting-data-to-create-match-statistics-using-flash-based-game-replay-fil) which does not answer my question really..

---

ATM my database looks something like this, this is a personal project so changing the DB is possible. No client input here to work around:
[image]

**I work with Laravel 5.3 (and am looking to learn Vue, very very soon).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using javascript. Collect all the match data and display your insights using [Crossfiler](https://github.com/square/crossfilter). It's a powerful package that let's you quickly browse through large datasets and present calculations on the client side using dimensions.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, basic JS and jQuery at the moment. I will defenitly have a look at it tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!